# How to search select and edit a specific part of a text file in python

Tags: python

Quite a beginner with programming and python, and I am currently writing a program for library book admin. I'm trying to select a piece of string from a text file, so when the user types in someone who has to check in a books user name, it comes up with the book and info. When i do this however, instead of printing the line in which the user number is, it prints the whole thing.
Please see my code:

```
searchphrase = raw_input("Please provide Your user ID:")
searchfile = open("Librarybooks.txt","r")
for line in searchfile:
    if searchphrase in line:
        print line 
    else:
        print "User not identified or invalid entry, please restart program"
        break
```

What i think it may be is that python does not recognize all the different lines in the text file, so thinks it is all one line. How would I lay this out to work? Or if you can see any obvious issues with my code any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking until the first line that *doesn't* match:

```
searchphrase = raw_input("Please provide Your user ID:")
searchfile = open("Librarybooks.txt","r")
for line in searchfile:
    if searchphrase in line:   # <== if it matches, then print and go to next line..
        print line 
    else:                      # <== if id doesn't match, exit the for loop
        print "User not identified or invalid entry, please restart program"
        break
```

try something like this instead:

```
for line in searchfile:
    if searchphrase in line:  # <== if matches, then print the line and break out of the for loop
        print line 
        break
else:                         # <== if the for loop finished without breaking, then the searchphrase was not in the file
    print "User not identified or invalid entry, please restart program"
```

this uses the else clause on the for-loop.

A simple way to debug these kinds of issues is to print out interesting variables before (and after) something changes. E.g.:

```
for line in searchfile:
    print "LINE: [%s]" % line  # I put it inside [] to check if there are any spaces at the end.
```

that way you can verify that your assumptions are correct.

Your IDE might have a debugger that lets you set breakpoints and inspect variables in a pretty visual user interface.